# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double what am I missing?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to pull session data (numbers) from Firestore and I get a java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double error.

I've read similar articles about converting between long and double although no implementations have worked for me yet, perhaps I have implemented them incorrectly. Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong.
I have tried this but also resulted in error:

```
Long x = (Long) session.get("rep_set1");
s.setRepsSet1((double) x);
```

This is the full method:

```
public class BenchSessionModel extends  Session {
    public BenchSessionModel() {
        type = ExerciseType.BENCH;
    }

    public static BenchSessionModel fromJson(Map<String, Object> session) {
        BenchSessionModel s = new BenchSessionModel();

        s.setRepsSet1((double) session.get("rep_set1"));
        s.setRepsSet2((double) session.get("rep_set2"));
        s.setRepsSet3((double) session.get("rep_set3"));
        s.setGoalReps((double) session.get("goal_reps"));
        s.setGoalWeight((double) session.get("goal_weight"));
        s.setRpe((double) session.get("rpe"));
        s.setWeight((double) session.get("weight"));
        s.setStallCount((int) session.get("stall_count"));

        String exp= (String) session.get("level");
        if(exp.equalsIgnoreCase("beginner")){
            s.setXpLevel("BEGINNER");
        }else{
            s.setXpLevel("ADVANCED");
        }
        s.setType(ExerciseType.BENCH);
        return s;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Long is not a Double, Double is not a Long. Just as ArrayList is not a String. We humans know they are both conceptually numbers, so they seem like they should be convertible. The compiler doesn't. You can call `someLong.doubleValue()`, which will give you a primitive double that will be autoboxed into a Double if necessary.

Comment: The egg of a pigeon isn't the egg of a chicken, no matter how often you scream "be the egg of a chicken" at it.

Comment: You can cast a `long` to `double`, but you cannot cast a `Long` to `double`.

Comment: @GhostCat how can I experimentally test this hypothesis without concerning my neighbours?

Comment: Okay these values are stored as Numbers in Firestore, and when I pull them I need them in the form of a double, how do I do that? They are coming from Firestore as a long it would seem

Comment: Your question was closed as a DUPLICATE to an existing question. There is a LINK to that question right on the top of the page! Also note that the one answer that came in ALSO gives you the correct way to do this. Where: the real answer is to do proper research. Instead of spending 10 minutes to get all your data into a question, spend 5, 10 minutes using a search engine, for example by putting your exception message into it. Rest assured: 99.999% of all such basic questions have been asked and explained before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Long x = (Long) session.get("rep_set1");
if(x != null){
    s.setRepsSet1(x. doubleValue());
}
```

Long object has a doubleValue() method, you can use it.